# Question in bash script

Tags: bash, centos

I am writing a simple bash script to show system information. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
hostn=$(hostname)
system=$(uname -a)
cpu=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" | cut -d : -f 2)
disk=$(df -h | grep -v "tmpfs" | awk '{print $1 "  " $4}')

printf -v serverinfo "Hostname:\t%s\nCPU:\t%s\nDisk:\t%s\nSystem:t%s\n" $hostn $cpu $disk $system
echo "$serverinfo"
```

The result displayed is in incorrect format:

```
Hostname:       KASH1LFCE01
CPU:    Intel(R)
Disk:   Xeon(R)
System:tCPU
Hostname:       E5-2650
CPU:    v3
Disk:   @
System:t2.30GHz
Hostname:       Filesystem
CPU:    Avail
Disk:   /dev/sdc
System:t12G
Hostname:       /dev/sda1
CPU:    431M
Disk:   Linux
System:tKASH1LFCE01
Hostname:       2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64
CPU:    #1
Disk:   SMP
System:tTue
Hostname:       May
CPU:    31
Disk:   21:57:07
System:tUTC
Hostname:       2016
CPU:    x86_64
Disk:   x86_64
System:tx86_64
Hostname:       GNU/Linux
CPU:
Disk:
System:t
```

The CPU information is printed in different lines and same with the uname -a information.

Comment: Quote the variables in the `printf` line.

Comment: You're also missing the backslash after `System:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the variables, otherwise the spaces will cause them to be split into separate arguments.

```
printf -v serverinfo "Hostname:\t%s\nCPU:\t%s\nDisk:\t%s\nSystem:\t%s\n" "$hostn" "$cpu" "$disk" "$system"
```

You should generally quote your variables all the time, except when you know that you need them to be split into words.